# easymock unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I had this error in my code, so I wrote a simple example to try to identify where the error lies.

I have a ClassA, that depends on two services ServiceA and ServiceB, I'm trying to test ClassA, and mocking ServiceA and ServiceB.

```
  /**
 * Last edited by: $Author: cg $
 * on: $Date: 17 Jun 2011 11:36:25 $
 * Filename: $RCSfile: ClassA.java,v $
 * Revision: $Revision:   $
 */
package easy;

import java.util.HashMap;


/** 
 * 
 * @version $Revision: $, $Date: 17 Jun 2011 11:36:25 $ 
 */
public class ClassA {
    private ServiceA serviceA;
    private ServiceB serviceB;
    public ClassA(ServiceA a, ServiceB b) {
        this.serviceA = a;
        this.serviceB = b;        
    }
    public String process(String p) {
        HashMap<String,String> a = serviceA.getServiceA(p);
        String ret = serviceB.getServiceB(a);
        return ret;
    }
}


interface ServiceA{
    HashMap<String,String>getServiceA(String s);
}

interface ServiceB{
    String getServiceB(HashMap<String,String> p);
}
```

My testing is the following:

```
/**
 * Last edited by: $Author: cg $
 * on: $Date: 17 Jun 2011 11:43:05 $
 * Filename: $RCSfile: ClassATest.java,v $
 * Revision: $Revision:   $
 */
package easy;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.eq;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;

import java.util.HashMap;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.IMocksControl;
import org.junit.Test;
/**
 * 
 * @version $Revision: $, $Date: 17 Jun 2011 11:43:05 $
 */
public class ClassATest {

    @Test
    public void testProcess() {
        IMocksControl mockery = EasyMock.createControl();
        mockery.resetToStrict();
        mockery.checkOrder(true);

        ServiceA serviceA = EasyMock.createMock("ServiceA",ServiceA.class);
        ServiceB serviceB = EasyMock.createMock("ServiceB",ServiceB.class);

        ClassA a = new ClassA(serviceA, serviceB);

        String myParam = "My Test";

        HashMap<String,String> retFromServiceA = new HashMap<String,String>();
        retFromServiceA.put("my", "name");
        expect(serviceA.getServiceA(eq(myParam))).andReturn(retFromServiceA);
        expect(serviceB.getServiceB(retFromServiceA)).andReturn(myParam);

        mockery.replay();
        String actual = a.process(myParam);
        mockery.verify();

        Assert.assertEquals(myParam, actual);
    }
}
```

the result is failing because the actual return is null.

I tried to debug into the code, and I realize that although in my expectations I say I expect **ServiceA.getServiceA** to return **retFromServiceA**, it's not. it's returning **null**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceA and ServiceB were created without using the mockery control, so you should use:

```
EasyMock.replay(serviceA, serviceB);
```

prior to executing the process method